# Phase and group velocity - deriving phase changes into animation

Tags: waves, velocity, superposition, phase-velocity

I have a question about the phase and group velocity topic. I am making an animation in Python showing both group and phase velocity changes. Let's assume we have 2 waves: $y_1 = A\cos(w_{1}t-k_{1}x)$ and $y_2 = A\cos( w_{1}t-k_{1}x)$. Superpositon of $y_1$ and $y_2$ is $y_3 = 2 A\cos\left(\frac{\left(t\left(w_{1}+w_{2}\right)-x\left(k_{1}+k_{2}\right)\right)}{2}\right)\cdot \cos\left(\frac{\left(t\left(w_{1}-w_{2}\right)-x\left(k_{1}-k_{2}\right)\right)}{2}\right)$. Is there any way to derive "phase changes", formula to accurately animate green dot moving from $y_3$ like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tlM9vq-bepA)? (the green moving dot starting from 0:31).

Comment: I'm just guessing here because I haven't thought about it too much yet, but I think what you'll have to do is calculate the phase velocity of $y_3$ first. Then calculate the position $x$ as a function of phase velocity $v$ and time $t$. Then substitute the values of $x$ and $t$ into $y_3$ to get the instantaneous position of the green dot.

Comment: combined with @Chris Long answer it is clearly a solution I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Paddy's comment is the correct method. In full it is:

$$y_3 = 2 A\underbrace{\cos\left(\frac{\left(t\left(w_{1}+w_{2}\right)-x\left(k_{1}+k_{2}\right)\right)}{2}\right)}_\text{waves within wavepacket}\cdot \underbrace{\cos\left(\frac{\left(t\left(w_{1}-w_{2}\right)-x\left(k_{1}-k_{2}\right)\right)}{2}\right)}_\text{envolpe function}$$

As the first term is the waves within the wavepacket (as smaller wavelength than for envelope, or larger wavenumber $k_1+k_2>\left|k_1-k_2\right|$) then we find x by setting the parameter of $\cos$ to a constant.

$$\frac{\left(t\left(w_{1}+w_{2}\right)-x\left(k_{1}+k_{2}\right)\right)}{2}=\text{const}$$

For ease I will let the constant be zero:

$$\implies x=\frac{w_{1}+w_{2}}{k_{1}+k_{2}}t$$

Thus, the coordinates of the green point are:

$$\left(\underbrace{\frac{w_{1}+w_{2}}{k_{1}+k_{2}}t}_x,\quad \underbrace{2 A\cos\left(\frac{\left(t\left(w_{1}-w_{2}\right)-\frac{w_{1}+w_{2}}{k_{1}+k_{2}}t\left(k_{1}-k_{2}\right)\right)}{2}\right)}_{y_3}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Working perfectly!